# How to modify data.frame using both function and list or vector

Tags: list, function, loops, replace

In my data frame, I would like to replace in a new column the value by the one present in another column from the same line.
I was able to write this function which works :

```
change <- function (x, col, df) {
  df[df$object==x, col] <- x
  assign('df',df,envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

With this code, if i write :

```
t2 <- change("car", "vehicle",t2)
```

I modify the data frame t2 by creating a new column named 'vehicule' and in which "car" will be write only if in the column object "car" is written.

Now I would like to do the same, but by using a list or a vector. For instance.

```
test = c("car","bus","plane")
change <- function (list, col, df) {
   for (x in list) {
     df[df$Gene.name==x, col] <- x
     assign('df',df,envir=.GlobalEnv) 
   }
}
```

But this code doesn't work at all. I tried several but any of them work. I'm mainly used dplyr tidyr and other packages and I'm not at all confortable with function and loop.

The goal is to write in this new column "vehicule" the value "car", "bus" or "plane" according the value present in object.

Can you help me ?

Thank you a lot for your help !

**Up date :**

Thanks for for responding. Actually it's juste a column with the name of different genes.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kngk5.png)

What I want to do is to create another column named "label" in which I indicate to which complex each gene belongs.
I manage to do it with the code you can see below :

```
change.in.col <- function (x, col, df, y) {
  df[df$Gene.name==x, col] <- y
  assign('df',df,envir=.GlobalEnv)}
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf1", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf2", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf3", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf4", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf5", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf6", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf7", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf8", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf9", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf10", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf11", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf12", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf13", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf9b", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf7l", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf4b", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Tbp", "label",df=t1, "TFIID")
t1 <-change.in.col("Supt20h", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Supt3", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Supt7l", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf5l", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Taf6l", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Tada2a", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Tada2b", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Atxn7l1", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Atxn7l2", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Atxn7l3", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Tada1", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Tada3", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Kat2a", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Kat2b", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Usp22", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Trrap", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Sf3b3", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
t1 <-change.in.col("Sf3b5", "label",df=t1, "SAGA")
```

Now to make it easy and to avoid having to write the same thing a thousand times, I would like to create first at all a list of gene for each complex (TFIID or SAGA or other), and thereafter use only one time the function change.in.col to write the name of the appropriate complex in the column "label". But for that I have to change the function change.in.col to make it able to read one by one each gene in the list and write the name of the complexe in the column label.
I guess I need to add a loop or something like that, but I do not manage to do it :/

Thank a lot in advance for your help

Comment: For me it's not really obvious what you plan to do. Could you please provide a sample of your dataframe t2?

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for for responding.

Comment: From where do you know which gene corresponds to which complex (TFIID or SAGA etc.)? Do you have a list in which they are assigned? If you don't have such a list it's not possible to fully automatize your task before preparing one.